# beforeFind() add conditions

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to filter EVERYTHING that's returned in my App based on a client condition.  This is in my AppModel:

```
public function beforeFind($queryData) {
    parent::beforeFind();
    $queryData['conditions'] = array('client_id' => 2);
    $this->log($queryData);
}
```

It's not filter the returned content though, but the condition info shows up in the log.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With beforeFind() you should return the `$queryData` array that you have modified if you want the find to use it. This is your current problem.

```
public function beforeFind($queryData) {
    parent::beforeFind();
    $queryData['conditions'] = array('client_id' => 2);
    return $queryData;
}
```

However, you have a couple of other small issues that could cause you problems down the line.

1. You should not set the conditions outright in your beforeFind(), but **add** to it. What if you are calling a find with conditions? Consider this:

   ```
   $this->MyModel->find('first', array(
       'conditions' => array(
           'MyModel.active' => 1
       )
   ));
   ```

   You want the find to use that condition, but also for your beforeFind() to automatically return only the result for the `client_id = 2`, using your beforeFind(). Unfortunately, with this line in your beforeFind():

   ```
   $queryData['conditions'] = array('client_id' => 2);
   ```

   You've just overwritten the conditions array completely, and lost your other condition of `MyModel.active = 1`.
2. You should also ensure that you are stating which model the field in the condition belongs to. This is good practice, and future proofs your code if you have two models which have a field called `client_id`. You can use `$this->alias` to get the current model's alias, which will also allow your code to work if you have used a different alias for the model.

**So your final code should be:**

```
    public function beforeFind($queryData) {
        parent::beforeFind();
        $queryData['conditions'][$this->alias . '.client_id'] = 2;
        return $queryData;
    }
```

Comment: Not beforeFilter but beforeFind. Also, if $query['conditions'] is not defined array_merge will not work. Try $query['conditions'] = is_array($query['conditions']) ? array_merge($query['conditions'], $defaultConditions) : $defaultConditions; You might want to edit ;)

Comment: Very useful post, have updated the function name as mentioned in the comment above. Something else to note, `parent::beforeFind()` expects an argument also. I removed that line from my implementation. (this is using Cake 1.3)

Comment: A much simpler and straight forward way would be to do `$queryData['conditions'][$this->alias . '.client_id'] = 2;`

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr Yes you are correct. This was a few years ago now but I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function beforeFind($queryData)
{
    if(parent::beforeFind($queryData) !== false)
    {
        $defaultConditions = array($this->alias . '.client_id' => 2);
        $queryData['conditions'] = array_merge($defaultConditions, $queryData['conditions']);
        return $queryData;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I followed BadHorsie's solution and abstracted it bit more as following:

- Checking the result of the parent's beforeFind before going further
- Using array_merge in the other order so that the default conditions
  are really default
- Using $this->alias so that you dont need to change the class name

Answer (score 0):

try changing to:

```
public function beforeFind($queryData) {
    parent::beforeFind();
    $queryData['conditions'] = array('client_id' => 2);    
    $this->log($queryData);
    return $queryData; //return the modified $queryData
}
```